# Can I use nosamplecontent run mode with publish run mode. If so, what is the use?

Tags: aem

Can I use nosamplecontent run mode with publish. If yes then what is the use, becasue the author may or may not have the sample content.

I tried from command line, what happened was that it set the `sling.run.mode=publish,nosamplecontent`. But this shouldn't be done, as the run mode was already set, and i ran the jar file previously also.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use just like with author run mode: at the time of first start if you do not need demo geometrixx content there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The nosamplecontent run mode can only be used during first installation only.
 https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/configure_runmodes.html#Installation%20Run%20Modes